# If two morphisms are isomorphic as sets in a category, then are they isomorphic as objects in the arrow category?

Tags: category-theory

Let's say we have the category of sets, and say we have a morphism between two objects in this category. Then, this morphism is in itself a set, since functions are defined through sets. So, let's say we have two functions (between two fixed objects $f,g:A \to B$) which are isomorphic in the category when considered as objects themself (sets), would this imply they are isomoprhic as objects in the arrow category as well? Would this always be the case even in general categories? If not, what constraints are needed so that it is?

Comment: Morphisms are elements of sets, not sets themselves (ignoring foundational questions, which are irrelevant). Elements of a set can be equal, but not isomorphic.

Comment: If you are in the category of sets at least , isn't it true that any function f:A-> B is a function in itself ? @varkor

Comment: I didn't understand. Coudl you rephrase @Randall

Comment: Too long for a comment, made an answer, which I'm sure will attract downvotes.

Comment: It's still not clear:  "two functions between two fixed objects."  Does that mean $f,g: A \to B$ or $f:A \to A$, $g:B \to B$?

Comment: the first case,, @Randall

Comment: By my deleted answer, $f$ and $g$ will always be isomorphic as sets since $|A|=|A|$.  You are now asking if *all* maps $f,g: A  \to B$ are always isomorphic in the arrow category.  Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider a function $f : A \rightarrow B$. It is an arrow in the category of sets, but as you mention, it is a set too: namely, $f \subset A \times B$. So, we can consider $f$ to be an object in the category of sets. Your questions asks whether, given two functions $f,g : A \rightarrow B$, an isomorphism $f \cong g$ as objects in $Set$ implies an isomorphism $f \cong g$ as objects in the arrow category.

To show why this is false, consider the two simple facts.

1. **A function $f : A \rightarrow B$ has cardinality $|A|$.** Indeed, $f$ can be written as $\{(a,f(a)) : a \in A\}$, so the map $A \rightarrow f : a \mapsto (a,f(a))$ is a bijection.
2. **If $f$ is an isomorphism in a category, and $f \cong g$ in the arrow category, then $g$ is also an isomorphism.** Suppose $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : C \rightarrow D$. If $f$ is an isomorphism, it has an inverse $f^{-1}$, and if $f \cong g$, then there are invertible maps $u : A \rightarrow C$ and $v : B \rightarrow D$ such that $g \circ u = v \circ f$. Then $g \circ (u \circ f^{-1} \circ v^{-1}) = Id_D$ and $(u \circ f^{-1} \circ v^{-1}) \circ g = Id_C$, so $g$ is invertible too.

Now, a counter-example is easy. Take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$ as functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. They have the same domain, hence the same cardinality, so they are isomorphic as sets. However, they cannot be isomorphic in the arrow category, since $f$ is an isomorphism and $g$ is not.

Comment: "If f
 is an isomorphism"... why do you suppose that f is an isomorphism and f,g to have different domain and codomain? In the question, we talk about fixed domain and codomain.

Comment: It's still true if they have the same domain and codomain; just set $C=A$ and $D=B$. I  just gave a more general statement.